# Change EditText Value after Clicking a Button in Custom Adapter

Tags: android

I have an option in my listview to change the number of item quanities depending on customer's desire. I have a `static Integer qty =1;` declared as global variable. When I click the "+" or "-" button, it does change the value of the quantity after I pass the value of the quantity to the next activity. But the text of the EditText is not changing.

here is part of my CustomAdapter

```
holder.item_qty.setText(qty.toString());
    holder.Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            qty++;
            //I know I have to do something here
            //holder.item_qty.setText(qty.toString()); <-- DID NOT WORK


        }
    });

    holder.Sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(qty>0)
            qty--;
            //I know I have to do something here
            ////holder.item_qty.setText(qty.toString()); <-- DID NOT WORK


        }
    });
```

**EDIT**: I changed the `static Integer qty =1;` to `Integer qty =1` because whenever I go back to the previous Activity, the quantity remains the samme. So I removed the static to make the qty=1 again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing data to other activity you should use intent.

```
String string="this is a text";
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), classname.class);
intent.putExtra(string, data);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then next step is to retrieve data.

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID");
```

Then set text in Edit Text use

```
editText.setText(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set text in EditText, something like this:

```
holder.item_qty.setText(qty.toString());
    holder.Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            qty++;
            //I know I have to do something here

           // inflate your textview here
           TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
           tv.setText(qty.toString())
        }
    });

    holder.Sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(qty>0)
            qty--;
            //I know I have to do something here

            // inflate your textview here
           TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
           tv.setText(qty.toString())
        }
});
```

You need to get current TextView from the view received in the `onClick()` method.

Comment: I did this a while ago. Still not changing the value of the EditText.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

```
in onClickListener set text for editText Listener

holder.item_qty.setText(qty.toString());
    holder.Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            qty++;

            holder.item_qty.setText(""+qty);

        }
    });

    holder.Sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(qty>0)
            qty--;
            holder.item_qty.setText(""+qty);


        }
    });
```

Comment: holder.item_qty is my EditText